# Ruby NoMethodError in Redmine from script/runner

Tags: ruby, redmine, nomethoderror

I have some Ruby code I need to execute in the Redmine Ruby app in order to enable a module in all projects at once.

Surprisingly, ruby does access the Projects, but raises a NoMethodError when accessing a few particular methods inside each of the "Project" objects.

Here is the code:

```
Project.find(:all).each do |project|

  print "Enabling modules for project '#{project.identifier}' ... "

  puts project.methods.sort            # this does print "enabled_module_names"
  puts project.enabled_module_names

end
```

This fails with:

```
hostname:/srv/apps/redmine# script/runner  vendor/plugins/customplugin/lib/enable_modules.rb
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:260:in `method_missing': undefined method `enabled_module_names' for #<Project:0x7f28985c1cb0> (NoMethodError)
    from vendor/plugins/customplugin/lib/enable_modules.rb:14
    from vendor/plugins/customplugin/lib/enable_modules.rb:7:in `each'
    from vendor/plugins/customplugin/lib/enable_modules.rb:7
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `eval'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/commands/runner.rb:46
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from script/runner:3
```

I have scratched my head a lot, but I can't grasp why would the code find the "Project" symbol but not the methods within, especially as "project.methods" does indeed list "enabled_module_names".

Any help most welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that enable_module_names is an instance method?

Is it within `Project.instance_methods`?

**Edit (summary of the comments below):**

In earlier versions, you have to use following:

```
enabled_module_names = project.enabled_modules.collect(&:name)
```

The getter is present in later versions only (see [rev.4460](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/repository/revisions/4460/diff/trunk/app/models/project.rb) for details of this change)

Comment: Ah, sorry, it should be Project.instance_methods. Will fix it in answer

Comment: Yes it does appear: "enabled_module_names=". This makes sense as an instance method (the list of enabled modules is particular for each given project). But yet it throws "NoMethodError".

Comment: Hm, then it looks like it's a setter. So, project.methods outputs "enabled_module_names", while Project.instance_methods outputs "enabled_module_names=" Right?

Comment: Yes. But I copied originally from https://github.com/EugenMayer/enable_chiliproject_modules/blob/master/scripts/enableModules.rb where it is used as a propety, and I'd swear this worked when I tested it two weeks ago... :?. And no, it seems a setter in both cases "enabled_module_names=".

Comment: Isn't there any preparation step you have to do? Migrate database, run some config script... Setter is there, that's good, but you need a getter, which is missing. Maybe it is generated dynamically, by calling some other method on that project object. Sorry, I don't know Redmine at all, so I'm just guessing what it could be at this phase.

Comment: Thank you. It turns out it was a setter only. The getter seems to exist in later versions only. I had to use: "enabled_module_names = project.enabled_modules.collect(&:name)" (copied from a later version). I'll be happy to accept your reply if you summarize this ;).

Comment: added reference to the change in redmine